# How can I log in this site using java?

Tags: java, debugging, web-scraping, httpclient

I was trying to log in this site using HttpClient:
https://translator.wiitrans.cn/

After trying all day, I just can not get the logged page. This is my code:

```
public class SimpleClient {
    static String code = "";
    static String captchaUrl= "https://passport.wiitrans.cn/code";

    public static void logIn() throws IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
//        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://passport.wiitrans.cn/");
        List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("account", xxxxx));
        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", xxxxx));
        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", code));
        formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("autologin", "1"));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity1 = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://passport.wiitrans.cn/");
        httppost.setEntity(entity1);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String set_cookie = response.getFirstHeader("Set-Cookie").getValue();
        System.out.println(set_cookie.substring(0, set_cookie.indexOf(";")));
        System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++=");
        System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++=");
        System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++=");

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://translator.wiitrans.cn/");
        httpget.setHeader("Cookie", set_cookie);
        HttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity2.getContent()));
        String line = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        code = Captcha.getCaptcha(captchaUrl);
        try {
            logIn();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The captcha is downloaded and input manually, can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: How do you know the CAPTCHA code to send in the login request?

Comment: edit: the captcha is downloaded and input manually.

Comment: The login url is `https://passport.wiitrans.cn/Login/login`. You should send `account`, `password` (encrypted), `code` and `autologin` in form data. `code` is the captcha code shown in the image. dunno how to get the code for login from captcha image